# What is this plant with broad, heart-shaped leaves and red veins?

Tags: identification

My co-worker gave me  hostas two years ago.  In addition to how much I have enjoyed watching these grow, I have enjoyed getting all sorts of nice ground covers that came along for the ride.  This one, however, I have never seen before.  It might be a weed for all I know, but it looks like something I would see in a nursery.  I am in Maryland, to give you in idea of zones.

[image]

Added an additional picture showing the stem.  [image]

Comment: It does look like a Begonia. The only thing is the frost would kill it. The pic does help. Did your co-worker give it to you this year after the leaves came out?

Comment: Thanks for the feed back.  I think this little fella came with the plants I got from a coworker 3 years ago.  It probably came up the past few years, but I either didn't notice it or mistakenly cut it down.

Comment: It could be a seedling.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a begonia...it looks very happy there! That's my guess anyhoo until it flowers...

Comment: I see what you mean.  That is a very good candidate.  I did a Google search on it, and there are several varieties of begonia that look similar.  Wikipedia says that begonia is the 6th largest genera of flowering plants with about 1500 species, so I might have to wait and see!  I'll see if I can post a better picture today to provide a better view.

Comment: Maybe *Begonia radicans* Vellozo 1831 (shrimp begonia)?

Comment: Shoot. Jmusser...I couldn't find it...way cool you were able to get down to a variety! I'll keep trying...later!

Answer (score 2):

It is Begonia grandis, or a B. grandis hybrid. It is considered a tender perennial, and I've tried to keep it here in Zone 5a without success. It is not difficult to control (i.e., it is not rampantly invasive) and it can produce white to pink flowers late in the summer. If happy, it can produce bulbils at the leaf axis, which will spread it. It is lovely among hostas and other shade plants.

Answer (score 0):

I have these flowers also. I was told they are a bleeding heart flower because they have heart shaped leaves with bright red blood looking veins running threw them !